# About details about any running process on computer

Tags: java, cpu

My project is "process migration".I want to measure load taken by a particular executing process on cpu using java.Accordingly,process which is requiring large load than other processes is to be migrated to the another computer for further execution.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can use `ps` for example the process using `/proc/` but I would look at top or `time` the process. All command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a linux system, you could use ps or [top](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm) commands to obtain information about processes currently running.

You can use the Runtime.exec() methods to execute these commands from within Java. For example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps")
```

If you need to specify arguments use a String array.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "ps", "-e" })
```

Whichever method you use, you'll need to open file descriptors on the Process object returned from exec() to send it input or obtain its output:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...command...");
InputStream input = process.getInputStream();
```

Then you will need to parse the result.